# convert list<list<string>> to dictionary<list<string>,int>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

```
Dictionary<List<string>, int> dictionary = input.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x =>x.Count());
```

This isn't working, what should I be doing?
GroupBy only compares references of list.So how can I compare elements of list?

input is in List< List < string >> and i need it in a dictionary.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why would you want a dictionary keyed by a list? And what do you mean by "ain't working"? This looks like it should compile (besides a typo you've got).

Comment: "this ain't working" is hardly a good description of what's happening. You haven't described your input or the result you're seeing. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question.

Comment: Why would you group on a list? This would be pointless as the default comparer just compares references, so you always end up with one list in each group.

Comment: Omg, you just gave me a reason to stay FAR away from LINQ (in fact I never used it)! Did you evaluate how the compiler will translate such line in bytecode (even if you are able to fix it)? Did you evaluate how many stupid things it could do just because you want to write a line of code instead of 4 lines of concise/correct/indisputable non-LINQ code? I hope your is just a curiosity or training on LINQ and not real code.

Comment: @ceztko so you're convinced that LINQ is stupid and unefficient, even though by your own admission you've never used it?

Comment: @MattDavey: good objection. No, I don't believe LINQ is stupid and inefficient. I just think that such a powerful tool should be used 1) when there something more interesting to express 2) with classes structured as a relational model. As it's a long time I don't have to deal with relational model, this question was really helpful for me to think "hey, it's a powerful tool but something I won't miss for the context I'm working now".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Dictionary<List<string>, int> dictionary = str.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x =>x.Key.Count);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = input.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key.toString(), x =>x.Count());
```

Comment: fiver - I was just a suggestion to try the same thing using dictionary . I am not good with java or mobile coding